# How to scale down an activity's content view in z-axis while it popping up a dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

Assuming that we a an activity and it pops up a modal view to pick up a category.

While that modal view pops up, the activity's content view scales down a little bit gradually as the image shows.

Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the modal view to be a dialog, it's easier to get the selected item by setting a callback. I am really not a big fan of `onActivityResult`. So the solution is quite simple:

1. Create a DialogFragment and set its' gravity `Gravity.Bottom` and make it full screen width by setting its' size in `DialogFragment#onStart`:

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dm.widthPixels, (int) (dm.heightPixels * 0.7f));
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffffff));
```

2. Perform an animation on activity's content view. But there is a black background, so we have to create a container for setting the black(#000000) background and then scale the real content view with cool animation.

```
    - layout
      - container(#000000)
        - real content view(to perform scale animation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make activity with Theme.Dialog, and start it like this

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.scale_z, R.alpha);
```

Use google to search info about writing animations.

Other method is just get root view of activity and scale it, when dialog opens.